# Why doesn't this setTimeout-based code work in Firefox with a small timeout (works in Internet Explorer/Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, cross-browser, settimeout

I have the following code which demonstrates the difference in calling a long-running function directly from an event trigger, vs. using `setTimeout()`.

**Intended behavior:**

- When the first button is pressed, it appears pressed, the calculation runs for several seconds, then when the calculation finishes, the button appears depressed again and the second column changes from "not calculating yet" to "calculation done". (I won't elaborate on why that is supposed to happen; [it's explained in linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575011/119280).)
- When the second button is pressed, the button depresses immediately; the second column immediately changes to "calculating..." text. When the calculation finishes several seconds later, the second column changes from "calculating..." to "calculation done".

**What actually happens:**

- This works perfectly in Chrome (both buttons behave as expected)
- This works perfectly in [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8)
- This does NOT work in Firefox (v.25) as-is. Specifically, the second button behaves 100% as the first one.

  - Changing the timeout in `setTimeout()` from `0` to `1` has no effect
  - Changing the timeout in `setTimeout()` from `0` to `500` **works**

Which leaves me with a big conundrum.

According to the whole reason behind why `setTimeout()` works whereas lack of one doesn't, the delay should have zero effect on how things work, **since `setTimeout()`'s main purpose is to change the queuing order here, NOT to delay things**.

So, why is it not working with delay 0 or 1 on Firefox, but works as expected with delay 500 (and works with any delay on Internet Explorer 8/Chrome)?

UPDATE: In addition to source code below, I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2YBE/30/). But for some reason JSFiddle refuses to even load on my Internet Explorer 8, so for that testing, the code below is required.

UPDATE2: Someone raised the possibility of there being an issue with configuration setting `dom.min_timeout_value` in Firefox. I have edited it from 4 to 0, restarted the browser, and nothing was fixed. It still fails with a timeout of 0 or 1 and succeeds with 500.

---

Here is my source code - I simply saved it to a HTML file on C: drive and opened in all three browsers:

```
<html><body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<table border=1>
    <tr><td><button id='do'>Do long calc - bad status!</button></td>
        <td><div id='status'>Not Calculating yet.</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id='do_ok'>Do long calc - good status!</button></td>
        <td><div id='status_ok'>Not Calculating yet.</div></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
function long_running(status_div) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 700; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < 200; k++) {
                result = result + i + j + k;
            }
        }
    }
    $(status_div).text('calclation done');
}

// Assign events to buttons
$('#do').on('click', function () {
    $('#status').text('calculating....');
    long_running('#status');
});
$('#do_ok').on('click', function () {
    $('#status_ok').text('calculating....');
    window.setTimeout(function (){ long_running('#status_ok') }, 0);
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

To test, you will need to change the nested loop boundaries to 300/100/100 for Internet Explorer 8; or to 1000/1000/500 for Chrome, due to different sensitivity of "this JS is taking too long"  error coupled with JavaScript engine speed.

Comment: NOTE: I read every single "related" question and none of them seem applicable. They are mostly about incorrect implementations of callback on settimeout (no function wrapper)

Comment: Maybe your DOM isn't ready. (http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @Moob - Unlikely. I could replicate the issue using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2YBE/31/), with onDomReady set to on.

Comment: I cant replicate this issue. It works for me. (+ you were right about the dom ready)

Comment: I am also encountering this very same problem in Firefox. I built a test suite for some code I'm working on which involves building a complicated DOM tree on the fly. After pressing "Build", I intended to display a message like "Building..." as the stack chugged away on the actual work, so I used the setTimeout trick to defer the work to the next frame.  But FF is really undoing a lot of what I have learned about the Event Loop. Different implementation of run-time environment is likely... but it's not like this trick is new or "cutting-edge".  Have you found anything since posting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a copy of the current (Jun 28, 2016) implementation of `window.setTimeout()` in Ubuntu.

As we can see, the timer gets inserted by this line of code:

```
  nsAutoPtr<TimeoutInfo>* insertedInfo =
    mTimeouts.InsertElementSorted(newInfo.forget(), GetAutoPtrComparator(mTimeouts));
```

Then a *few* lines below you have an `if()` statement:

```
if (insertedInfo == mTimeouts.Elements() && !mRunningExpiredTimeouts) {
...
```

The `insertedInfo == mTimeouts.Elements()` checks whether the timer that was just inserted already timed out. The following block does NOT execute the attached function, but the main loop will immediately notice that a timer timed out and thus it will skip the IDLE state (a yield of the CPU) that you are expecting.

This clearly (at least to me) explains the behavior you are experiencing. The rendering on the screen is another process (task/thread) and the CPU needs to be relinquished for that other process to get a chance to re-paint the screen. For that to happen, you need to *wait long enough* so your timer function does not get executed immediately and a yield happens.

As you've notice a pause of 500ms does the trick. You can probably use a smaller number, such as 50ms. Either way it is not going to guarantee that a yield happens, but chances are it will happen if the computer on which that code is running is not currently swamped (i.e. an anti-virus is not currently running full speed in the background...)

The complete `SetTimeout()` function from Firefox:

(location of the file in the source: `dom/workers/WorkerPrivate.cpp`)

```
int32_t
WorkerPrivate::SetTimeout(JSContext* aCx,
                          dom::Function* aHandler,
                          const nsAString& aStringHandler,
                          int32_t aTimeout,
                          const Sequence<JS::Value>& aArguments,
                          bool aIsInterval,
                          ErrorResult& aRv)
{
  AssertIsOnWorkerThread();

  const int32_t timerId = mNextTimeoutId++;

  Status currentStatus;
  {
    MutexAutoLock lock(mMutex);
    currentStatus = mStatus;
  }

  // It's a script bug if setTimeout/setInterval are called from a close handler
  // so throw an exception.
  if (currentStatus == Closing) {
    JS_ReportError(aCx, "Cannot schedule timeouts from the close handler!");
  }

  // If the worker is trying to call setTimeout/setInterval and the parent
  // thread has initiated the close process then just silently fail.
  if (currentStatus >= Closing) {
    aRv.Throw(NS_ERROR_FAILURE);
    return 0;
  }

  nsAutoPtr<TimeoutInfo> newInfo(new TimeoutInfo());
  newInfo->mIsInterval = aIsInterval;
  newInfo->mId = timerId;

  if (MOZ_UNLIKELY(timerId == INT32_MAX)) {
    NS_WARNING("Timeout ids overflowed!");
    mNextTimeoutId = 1;
  }

  // Take care of the main argument.
  if (aHandler) {
    newInfo->mTimeoutCallable = JS::ObjectValue(*aHandler->Callable());
  }
  else if (!aStringHandler.IsEmpty()) {
    newInfo->mTimeoutString = aStringHandler;
  }
  else {
    JS_ReportError(aCx, "Useless %s call (missing quotes around argument?)",
                   aIsInterval ? "setInterval" : "setTimeout");
    return 0;
  }

  // See if any of the optional arguments were passed.
  aTimeout = std::max(0, aTimeout);
  newInfo->mInterval = TimeDuration::FromMilliseconds(aTimeout);

  uint32_t argc = aArguments.Length();
  if (argc && !newInfo->mTimeoutCallable.isUndefined()) {
    nsTArray<JS::Heap<JS::Value>> extraArgVals(argc);
    for (uint32_t index = 0; index < argc; index++) {
      extraArgVals.AppendElement(aArguments[index]);
    }
    newInfo->mExtraArgVals.SwapElements(extraArgVals);
  }

  newInfo->mTargetTime = TimeStamp::Now() + newInfo->mInterval;

  if (!newInfo->mTimeoutString.IsEmpty()) {
    if (!nsJSUtils::GetCallingLocation(aCx, newInfo->mFilename, &newInfo->mLineNumber)) {
      NS_WARNING("Failed to get calling location!");
    }
  }

  nsAutoPtr<TimeoutInfo>* insertedInfo =
    mTimeouts.InsertElementSorted(newInfo.forget(), GetAutoPtrComparator(mTimeouts));

  LOG(TimeoutsLog(), ("Worker %p has new timeout: delay=%d interval=%s\n",
                      this, aTimeout, aIsInterval ? "yes" : "no"));

  // If the timeout we just made is set to fire next then we need to update the
  // timer, unless we're currently running timeouts.
  if (insertedInfo == mTimeouts.Elements() && !mRunningExpiredTimeouts) {
    nsresult rv;

    if (!mTimer) {
      mTimer = do_CreateInstance(NS_TIMER_CONTRACTID, &rv);
      if (NS_FAILED(rv)) {
        aRv.Throw(rv);
        return 0;
      }

      mTimerRunnable = new TimerRunnable(this);
    }

    if (!mTimerRunning) {
      if (!ModifyBusyCountFromWorker(true)) {
        aRv.Throw(NS_ERROR_FAILURE);
        return 0;
      }
      mTimerRunning = true;
    }

    if (!RescheduleTimeoutTimer(aCx)) {
      aRv.Throw(NS_ERROR_FAILURE);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return timerId;
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The JavaScript instruction `yield`, has nothing to do with what I am talking about. I am talking about the [sched_yield()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) functionality which happens when a binary process calls certain functions, such as `sched_yield()` itself, `poll()`, `select()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue with Firefox while toggling CSS classes using jQuery to control a CSS transition.

Increasing the duration of setTimeout to 50 from 0 helped, but as Alexis suggested this wasn’t 100% reliable.

The best (if longwinded) solution I found was to combine an interval timer with an IF statement to actually check whether the necessary styles had been applied before triggering the transition, rather using setTimeout and assuming execution had taken place in the intended order, e.g.

```
    var firefox_pause = setInterval(function() {
            //Test whether page is ready for next step - in this case the div must have a max height applied
        if ($('div').css('max-height') != "none") {
            clear_firefox_pause();
            //Add next step in queue here
        }
    }, 10);

    function clear_firefox_pause() {
        clearInterval(firefox_pause);
    }
```

In my case at least, this seems to work every time in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, the minimum value for setTimeout() calls [is configurable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Mozilla_preferences_for_uber-geeks#DOM_preferences) and defaults to 4 in current versions:

> `dom.min_timeout_value` The minimum length of time, in milliseconds,
>   that the window.setTimeout() function can set a timeout delay for.
>   This defaults to 4 ms (before 10 ms). Calls to setTimeout() with a
>   delay smaller than this will be clamped to this minimum value.

Values like 0 or 1 should behave like 4—no idea if that will cause delays in your code or just break it.

Comment: OK, I'm dead confused. It seems you're right experimentally - changing timeout to 5 worked. BUT, I don't get why this timeout value would affect things based on the description - it sounds to me as if FF would simply silently change 1 or 0 to "4"?

Comment: Also, FF document on the topic seems to indicate that all modern browsers to clamping, so why does Chrom have no issues?

Comment: Also, I just changed that value from 4 to 0 in my `about:config` and it didn't help!!!