# Listening browser reflow event

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, browser

I'm trying to listen browsers [reflow-events](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/08/17/when-does-javascript-trigger-reflows-and-rendering/) to get an idea what parts of a code are the most expensive ones. Reflow occurs when something must be (re)drawn to screen, for example when new element is added to DOM.

Is there a way to listen thease events for example in/with Javascript, for further analysis?

Comment: This would be similar to DOM mutation events, which are deprecated and were never widely supported. I think you should be using the browser's profiling features.

Comment: Take a look at chromes dev tools:  http://addyosmani.com/blog/performance-optimisation-with-timeline-profiles/

Comment: But is there a way to do it inside code?

Comment: I'm looking into this as well, I want to hook into the event to test if an element is visible after a reflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution it's to use the DOM MutationObserver class.
As the Docs point out:

> It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification.
>   [Api Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

The example on the site is pretty self explanatory

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: MutationObservers only listen to changes to the DOM tree. Changes in the DOM tree won't necessarily trigger a reflow, and these would only be a subset of the possible reflow triggers. For example, viewport resizing can cause layout recalculation, but DOM tree is not getting modified.