# Does changing attributes in a container element always cause repaints or reflows?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, repaint, reflow

Is changing, via JavaScript, an informational attribute such as a data attribute (or even a CSS class for that matter) in a main container element a performance hit EVEN IF THERE IS NO ASSOCIATED CSS? (There are no associated changes in the presentation of the DOM.) Would it be better, for example, to relegate the same attribute changes to a hidden input proxy, for example?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553328/listening-browser-reflow-event) , an answer suggests that all DOM mutations cause repaints or reflows. [This article](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) suggests they occur more selectively.  Attributes can be targeted in CSS selectors, so my guess would be that there must be some inherent cost as the browser assesses the POSSIBILITY of a repaint or reflow, but I'm unclear as to how significant this cost might be.

Comment: What's a "hidden input proxy"? Why do you need to change DOM attributes at all?

Comment: Yes, of course CSS rules need to be checked when you change something in the DOM, but fear not, browsers are pretty good at doing that efficiently. And they will avoid reflows for sure, which are only necessary when the *dimensions* of an element change.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes there are benefits to working with data attributes that are more elegant than any other solution.  I very much appreciate the input, Bergi.  Thanks.

Comment: I just witnessed a significant reflow (white flash across the site) when using `document.querySelectorAll('[href]')` as opposed to `document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')`. A browser engine works in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it in Chrome 52 with the `Paint flashing` option enabled in the developer tools.

When changing an attribute of a DOM element that's not relevant for its style, I saw no paint flashing. Neither with a custom attribute like `data-test="123"` nor with `class="non-existing-class"`.

I think you should test this with other browsers as well, but I don't see a problem setting attributes if you need it.

Comment: Nice experiment.  Thanks for making me aware of that tool, Christoph.