# Is DOM Reflow detectable?

Tags: javascript, reflow

I am developing a website which includes file upload and download.

The files are displayed in a table with some information about them.

I am reading them from an array which is built by PHP and then given to JavaScript via JSON. I am adding them to the table one by one. I am running a function which adjusts the font sizes of all elements in the table so that the font width is always 80% of the container width.

**Here is my problem:**

Sometimes it is leaving out a few lines. I can think of a few reasons why this would happen:

1. When I measure the width of an element using `offsetWidth`, a reflow is caused, which could maybe make the `offsetWidth` of other elements unavailable for a few milliseconds, so they are skipped.
2. The browser is not finished building the DOM when the function, which adjusts the font sizes, starts.

   - To be clear: I start it a few hundred milliseconds after I am finished adding everything to the table.
   - When I set that time to for example 300 milliseconds it skips more items than when I set it to 1000 milliseconds.

**My ideas for a solution are:**

1. Detect the reflow and wait until it is done.

   - This could solve the first reason
2. Force a reflow after everything is added to the table and wait until that is done.

   - This could solve the second problem.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: If "measure" here means retrieving a value, _reflow_  doesn't take place before all the JS has been executed. The DOM will be recalculated, if there are changes to it before retrieving. Also, "_The browser is not finished building the DOM when the function, which adjusts the font sizes starts_" is not possible. There's only a single thread which exeutes both, the reflow and JS. If the reflow has been started, any JS is not run before the reflow is ready.

Comment: You know that there is a `vw` unit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listening browser reflow event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553328/listening-browser-reflow-event)